# BACnet protocol stack in C#

Tags: c#

Im writing a customised C# application to communicate with BACnet devices. Is there any BACnet protocol stack written in c# which i can download the source code?

Comment: there's a few just google for it, I found this a few days ago http://bacsharp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try bacnet stack with source code:

http://bacsharp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to download via SVN using Tourtoise it asks for authentication . sourceforge authentication doesn't seem to work for SVN

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've tried it, but there's finally a NuGet package now, that is probably worth evaluating.

(But BacSharp is the husk/seed of a good project/provision.)

I'd also recommend the (advanced & free) VTS tool (- YABE is a sensible tool for a more high-level visual view).

Answer (score -1):

for anonymous checkout try:

svn checkout http://svn.code.sf.net/p/bacnet/code/tags/bacnet-stack-0-8.2/

This is what worked for me.
0.8.2 is the latest stable version as of Aug 23 2014.